# Resizing Canvas Macro in photoshop

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, resize, photoshop

I am trying to create a macro in photoshop that will resize my canvas to 4x the size of the existing image, leaving the original image as the upper left quadrant.

Currently I am doing it by hand, just using the crop tool and pulling the right corner down on each photo until it is approximately a 4x larger Square.

The images I am modifying are all squares and I want to create a 4x bigger square leaving the original square as the upper left quadrant.

Effectively it would be like resizing the canvas, pegging the image to the upper left and doubling the two dimensions.

Is this possible, via Javascript or any other method?

Thanks
Corey

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow
You can adjust the canvas size with a photoshop script. They come in three flavours VB, Applescript or JavaScript.

Here's something to get you started

```
// Call the source doc
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get original width and height
var w = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

// adjust canvas size four times original
// with the anchor in the top left
srcDoc.resizeCanvas(w*4, h*4, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
```

You also might want to look at the [photoshop CC javascript ref pdf](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf)